# "SyntaxError: invalid syntax error" when building python-3.8.9 source code as a rpm package on Centos 7.6

Tags: python-3.x, centos7, rpmbuild

I'm trying to build python3.8.9 source code as a rpm package on centos 7.6. My spec file is as follows:

```sh
# python-v3.8.9.spec
# sitelib for noarch packages, sitearch for others (remove the unneeded one)
%{!?python_sitelib: %global python_sitelib %(%{__python} -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())")}
%{!?python_sitearch: %global python_sitearch %(%{__python} -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib(1))")}

Name:           Python
Version:        3.8.9
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        python v3.8.9 rpm package
License:        Python
URL:            https://www.python.org/
Source0:        Python-3.8.9.tar.gz

BuildArch:      noarch
# BuildRequires:  python-devel

%description    
This is python-3.8.9 rpm package

%prep
%setup -q

%build
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python3
make %{?_smp_mflags}

# I'm in trouble here
%install
make DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT install

%clean
[ "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT" != "/" ] && rm -rf "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT"
make clean
 
%files
%doc
# For noarch packages: sitelib
%{python_sitelib}/*
# For arch-specific packages: sitearch
%{python_sitearch}/*


%changelog
```

I use `rpmbuild -bb python-v3.8.9.spec`. And then I got these error message when installing python-v3.8.9:

```sh
+ '[' noarch = noarch ']'
+ case "${QA_CHECK_RPATHS:-}" in
+ /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-compress
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile /usr/bin/python 1
Compiling /home/rpmcreater/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Python-3.8.9-1.el7.x86_64/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/_collections_abc.py ...
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/_collections_abc.py", line 58
    async def _coro(): pass
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


Compiling /home/rpmcreater/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Python-3.8.9-1.el7.x86_64/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/distutils/tests/test_build_ext.py ...
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/distutils/tests/test_build_ext.py", line 111
    code = textwrap.dedent(f"""
            tmp_dir = {self.tmp_dir!r}

            import sys
            import unittest
            from test import support

            sys.path.insert(0, tmp_dir)
            import xx

            class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
                def test_xx(self):
                    for attr in ('error', 'foo', 'new', 'roj'):
                        self.assertTrue(hasattr(xx, attr))

                    self.assertEqual(xx.foo(2, 5), 7)
                    self.assertEqual(xx.foo(13,15), 28)
                    self.assertEqual(xx.new().demo(), None)
                    if support.HAVE_DOCSTRINGS:
                        doc = 'This is a template module just for instruction.'
                        self.assertEqual(xx.__doc__, doc)
                    self.assertIsInstance(xx.Null(), xx.Null)
                    self.assertIsInstance(xx.Str(), xx.Str)


            unittest.main()
        """)
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Compiling /home/rpmcreater/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Python-3.8.9-1.el7.x86_64/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/email/mime/message.py ...
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/email/mime/message.py", line 17
    def __init__(self, _msg, _subtype='rfc822', *, policy=None):
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Compiling /home/rpmcreater/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Python-3.8.9-1.el7.x86_64/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/email/mime/multipart.py ...
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/email/mime/multipart.py", line 17
    *, policy=None,
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


Compiling /home/rpmcreater/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Python-3.8.9-1.el7.x86_64/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/zipimport.py ...
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/zipimport.py", line 134
    return None, [f'{self.archive}{path_sep}{modpath}']
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.nykA9y (%install)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.nykA9y (%install)
```

I can use commands `make` and `make install` to install python-3.8.9 on my centos 7 successfully.

This makes me confuse. In my opinion, installing python-3.8.9 via rpm is not fundamentally different from installing it by running `make && make install`  command manually. So, can anyone explained why did these happend? Am I making anything wrong?

This is my computer environment:

> OS: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
>
> kernel: 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64
>
> RPM version: 4.11.3

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you install Python via `rpm`, the installation tools just copy the compiled files from the .rpm archive to your system (and update the local rpm DB).
This is very different from compiling the source code with `rpmbuild`. I think you're trying to build Python 3.8 using an olded Python version that does not support some of the recent syntaxes.

Comment: Unfortunately I only see Python 3.6 in the [EPEL](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/11/) repositories for CentOS-7, but maybe with this version you can build Python3.8.

Comment: It won't help you build the RPM but you can get Python 3.8 for RHEL using [software collections](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/red-hat-software-collections-35-and-red-hat-developer-toolset-91-beta-now-available).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that RPM is trying to pre-compile all the python software in the RPM, but it is using `/usr/bin/python` (see the line "`/usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile /usr/bin/python 1`") which is **python2** on RHEL.

Packaging python is pretty complicated, so a hand-written specfile probably won't cut it if you're not very experienced with RPMs. I haven't done it in a while, but IIRC you need to override `%{_python}` (or similar) with the one compiled in your staging area, but I'm not positive off-hand. In theory you could skip the compilation all together, but that will make the bundled python run pretty slow because it would need to effectively recompile the entire standard library every time you imported something for the first time.

Another place to start would be looking at the specfiles in the SRPMS of EPEL or similar for other 3.x RPMs and work from there.